# How to connect AngularJS with OrientDB

Tags: angularjs, orientdb

I want to create a simple login form by using **AngularJS** and **OrientDB**.
IS IT POSSIBLE?
I'm new to both technologies.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. In order to get some answers you should show what you have tried sofar. Please read more on this topic in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

You can use the HTTP API : http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-REST.html

Hope it helps.